# Retrieve value out of XML document using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have the following XML which is returned to me after making an AJAX request.

```
<entry xml:base="url" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" 
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<id>URL</id>
<category term="SomeCategory" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"></category>
<link rel="edit" title="Table" href="Table(56)">
<link rel="SomeURL" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="table" href="table(56)/table1">
<link rel="SomeURL" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="table" href="table(56)/table2">
<link rel="SomeURL" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="table" href="table(56)/table3">
<link rel="SomeURL" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="table" href="table(56)/table4">
<title></title>
<updated>2016-01-16T02:35:51Z</updated>
<author>
    <name></name>
</author>
<content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
        <d:NewlyCreatedId m:type="Edm.Int32">56</d:NewlyCreatedId>
    </m:properties>
</content>
```

I'm trying to get the value `56` out of it using jQuery, this is my success method inside my AJAX method:

```
success: function (data) {
    var selectedId = data.find('d:NewlyCreatedId').val();
    alert(selectedId);
}
```

But this produces the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: data.find is not a function

Can someone suggest how I go about pulling the value our of this XML document please.

*** Update ***

I've tried that was suggested in the answers, however this is now returning null where I alert the selectedId.

Inside my success method I now have this:

```
var selectedId = $(data).find('d\\:NewlyCreatedId').text();
```

Updated the question with the complete XML document

*** update ***

I've been battling this all day, I changed my datatype within my ajax method to `xml`, tried looping through but with no avail.  Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn `data` in to a jQuery object to be able to call `find()`. Also note that you will need to escape the `:` in the tag name, and you need to use `text()` to get the `1` value from the node, not `val()`. Try this:

```js
success: function (data) {
    var selectedId = $(data).find('d\\:NewlyCreatedId').text();
    alert(selectedId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the code snippet, when I try your code and alert selectedId it appears to empty, even thought I can view the response in the browser and it has a valid number

Answer (score 1):

Or you could also pass the `dataType` option to the `$.ajax` request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/x.xml',
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function (xmlData) { console.log(xmlData); }
});
```